# How to store a PHP variable in a "global" way?

Tags: php, if-statement

That may not be the correct terminology, "global".

What I'm trying to figure out is this.

I've got something like:

```
<?php if (empty($nest)) {
   $mothercrying = 'all day long';
   echo 'Mother is crying '.$mothercrying;
} if (!empty($nest)) {
   echo 'Mother is NOT crying '.$mothercrying;
} ?>
```

Is there some way to declare `$mothercrying` inside of the first `if` so that I can use it in the second one, too?

Note that I can't declare `$mothercrying` before both `if` statements, as what I'm working with is actually a couple of hundred lines longer than this.

Comment: Try using session so that you can access your variable anywhere

Comment: @Nathan even if the code is a couple'a hundred lines longer? Why can't you declare the variable before the if. Also since you check for `if( empty($nest) )` why not replace `if (!empty($nest)) {` with an `else`

Comment: beside using session, you can also use `define()`, http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php. in most circumstances, global is evil

Comment: @bIgBoY the first `if` ends up doing a bunch of stuff which defines `$mothercrying` and it's condition also means that I don't want any of that stuff to happen if that condition isn't met. But certainly the `else` would be fine and probably better to use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [session](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

```
  session_start();

if (empty($nest)) {
   $mothercrying = 'all day long';
   $_SESSION['cry']= $mothercrying;
   echo 'Mother is crying '.$_SESSION['cry'];
} if (!empty($nest)) {
  if(isset($mothercrying)){
    $_SESSION['cry']= $mothercrying;
  }else{
    $_SESSION['cry']='all day long';
  }        
   echo 'Mother is NOT crying '.$_SESSION['cry'];
}
```

Comment: Add session_start() at the top of every file for you to be able to access the session.

Comment: how does this work ? If `$nest` is not empty then the code will through an error `Undefined index: cry ..` if `$_SESSION['cry']` is not declared before the first if.

Comment: 1. $nest is an array. You can't "echo" it. 2. OP said `Is there some way to declare $mothercrying inside of the first if so that I can use it in the second one, too?`. How does your solution solve this ?

Comment: 2. The use of session solved that problem because session is a global variable and can be used anywhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97822/discussion-between-bigboy-and-monace19).

Answer (score 1):

In both ways you can define constants, If you're defining constants in separate file then must include that file where you want to use:

```
define('MOTHER_CRYING', 'all day long');
```

**OR**

```
global $mothercrying;
$mothercrying = 'all day long';
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not a "global" issue. Both confitions are excluding each other. The second `if` should just be an `else` and your variable must be defined before your `if` statement. In case the second confition is true, the first one can only be false and your variable won't be defined!